# Class or Interface expected cocos2d-android

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use cocos2d-android in Android Studio following this [tutorial](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/), the problem is that I'm unable to add at myactivity.java:

```
protected CCGLSurfaceView _glSurfaceView;
```

Because AndroidStudio shows a message:

```
class or interface expected
```

I didn't see a class definition in the tutorial, before this I just added cocos2d-android.jar into libs folder as a library following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library).

Answer (score 0):

All types that you want to use in your Java code need to be defined somewhere. This can either happen in your own Java code or inside an external library.

In your case you want to use the class `CCGLSurfaceView`. That class is part of Cocos2D and defined inside that library. You however need to tell your Java code to load/include that specific class definition from the library. Otherwise this class is not known and you see the respective error about the compiler expecting a known class or interface.

Adding this line before your class definition **[*]** should solve your issue.

```
org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView;
```

This step can also be automatized in eclipse/AndroidStudio: Since you added Cocos2d as an external dependency, your IDE is ware of it and by using the following shortcut will automatically try to find a matching class within all dependencies and add the respective `import` statement:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (or via the menu *Source* → *Organize Imports*)

**[*]** If you follow the linked tutorial, then insert that line before definition of the class *SimpleGame*. See examples in the comments on the tutorial website.